# functional wrapper trouble with : X <| fun () -> A

Tags: f#, wrapper

So I just wanted to ask why this works :

```
let internal X th =
    foo()
    th()
    bar()

let Start() = 
    X <| fun () -> ( foo(); bar(); etc... )
```

And this doesn't work :

```
let internal XD A =
    let X th =
        foo()
        th()
        bar()
    (X <| fun () -> A)

let Start() = 
    XD ( foo(); bar(); etc... )
```

it's looking like the same for me but first variant works as wrapper and I completely can't understand how second variant works.

Comment: By doesn't work you mean logically the result is not same right?

Comment: So foo(); bar(); etc... must be called after foo() and before bar(). Like with my first variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is the correct code for 2nd version for what you want to achieve (without lambda using lazy values).

```
let internal XD (A:Lazy<unit>) =
    let X th =
        foo()
        th()
        bar()
    X <| (fun () -> A.Force())

let Start() = 
    XD ( lazy(foo(); bar();) )
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the confusing thing is that in your second version, the variable `A` is just a `unit`. The F# compiler infers this from the fact that you return `A` from a function that's used as `th` and the type of `th` is `unit -> unit`. This means that `foo` is called in `Start` before stepping in `XD`.

However, it is a bit difficult to tell what results were you expecting. Did you want to pass `foo` to `XD` as a function, instead of calling it immediately? If yes, then you'd need:

```
let internal XD A =
    let X th =
        foo()
        th()
        bar()
    (X <| fun () -> A()) // Change: Call A with unit argument: 'A ()'

XD foo // Change: Pass a function instead of calling it
```

Comment: the trouble is I can't pass function, there are two functions (or more) ... I will edit question in a second.

Comment: Maybe I just can't pass ( foo(); bar(); etc... ) and then make a lambda from them inside my function.

Comment: Simply I want to Surround ( foo(); bar(); etc... ) without converting it to lambda but I'm not sure if that is possible.